# how to disable button when it's clicked and enable another button using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to disable a button when it's clicked, and enable another button using AJAX.

This is the script for the like and dislike buttons:

```
function like(id,type,target){
    $.ajax({
        //condition for like and unlike button
        $('button').click(function like() {
            var classname = $(this).attr('id');

            if(classname == 'positive')
            { 
                $('button.positive').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $('button.negative').attr('disabled', false);
            }
            else
            {
                $('button.negative').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $('button.positive').attr('disabled', false);
            }
        }

        //like unlike for mysql database
        type:'POST',
        url:'ratinglike.php',
        data:'id='+id+'&type='+type,
        success:function(msg){
            if(msg == 'err'){
                alert('Some problem occured, please try again.');
            }else{
                $('#'+target).html(msg);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

HTML for like and unlike buttons:

```
<!-- Like Icon HTML -->
<!-- the php condition inside works but i need to refresh the page before i see its disabled -->
<button class="fa fa-thumbs-up" id = "positive" <?php if($userlike == 1){?>disabled<?php } ?>  onClick="like(<?php echo $trow['id']; ?>,1,'like_count<?php echo $trow['id']; ?>')"></button>&nbsp;

<!-- Like Counter -->
<span class="counter" id="like_count<?php echo $trow['id']; ?>"><?php echo $trow['like_num']; ?></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button class="fa fa-thumbs-down" id="negative" <?php if($userdislike == 1){?>disabled<?php } ?> onClick="like(<?php echo $trow['id']; ?>,0,'dislike_count<?php echo $trow['id']; ?>')" ></button>&nbsp;

<!-- Like Counter -->
<span class="counter" id="dislike_count<?php echo $trow['id']; ?>"><?php echo $trow['dislike_num']; ?></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: The button disable code should be in the success method of ajax if you want that to be executed on success.

Comment: I tested it its not working.@VinodChandak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this working sample. Please modify to meet your needs.

```js
//script for like and dislike button
function like(btn, id, type) {

  var button = $(btn);

  // disable button so it cant be click again
  button.prop('disabled', true);

  $.ajax({
    //like unlike for mysql database
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ratinglike.php',
    data: 'id=' + id + '&type=' + type,
    success: function(msg) {
      if (msg == 'err') {
        alert('Some problem occured, please try again.');
      } else {        
        var otherButton = button.siblings('button');

        button.prop('disabled', true);
        otherButton.prop('disabled', false);        
        
        // update counters
        updateCounter(button, 1);
        updateCounter(otherButton, -1);
      }
    },
    error: function(xhr, error) {
      button.prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });

}

function updateCounter(btn, value) {
   var counter = btn.next('.counter');
   var newCount = Math.max(0, parseInt(counter.text()) + value);
   
   counter.text(newCount);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Like Icon HTML -->
<button class="fa fa-thumbs-up" onClick="like(this, 10, 1)">Like</button>&nbsp;
<!-- Like Counter -->
<span class="counter">0</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button class="fa fa-thumbs-down" onClick="like(this, 10, 0)">DisLike</button>&nbsp;
<!-- Like Counter -->
<span class="counter">0</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Comment: this one works for me!!. Thanks @elegisandi but I want to know what is this line of code onClick="like(this, 10, 0)" why 10?

Comment: I just modified some of codes here but If you don't mind please explain to me the code, just want to learn new things. Thanks and God bless.

Comment: based on the function: it says btn, id, type where `btn` button being clicked, `id` the row id, `type` 1 = _like_, 0 = _dislike_

Comment: @janejoe if you dont mind upvoting, that would be really appreaciated thanks!

Comment: I already did. By the way I just found something problem here what if the number of likes and unlikes started with 0. So if I clicked the first button it will show up 1 and the other is -1 which is not what I want. Do you have any idea how to fix that?

Comment: cool thing I never thought It's just simple as you did. @elegisandi God bless you

Comment: hey @elegisandi I,m a little shy to ask you this but what do you think I should do if I want the first click will just update the button + 1 and the other button will just the same but the next click will be the  +1 the clicked button and -1 the other one. I tried using the if else statement using php but the problem is I need to refresh the page to see the effect. Don't worry I think this will be the last question for this. Thanks and God bless.

Comment: you mean a user can click both buttons?

Comment: Nah. Let me give you a scenario. For example the user will click the button for the first time, what will happen on that is the like/unlike button will +1 but the other one should remain the same because the user record start with 0 but the user second click will the +1  and -1 condition because on the second click the user has already a record so he/she can like/dislike his/her added record. @elegisandi

Answer (score 1):

```
    You can use a css class for it :
    If it is a link means <a> tag then you can use the following css class
    .disabled {
            pointer-events: none;
        }

    and you can add class or remove class on event as
    $("a").addClass('disabled') // you should use button id here
    or
    $("a").removeClass('disabled') // you should use button id here
    if it is button then you can use disabled property of the input tag like
    $("#button1").prop('disabled','disabled')
    or
    $("button2").removeProp('disabled')

I am giving you an example:
$("#button1").on('click',function(){
 $("#button1").prop('disabled','disabled');
 $("#button2").removeProp('disabled')
});
//and same for button2
```

Comment: You sould always use prop in this case, not remove attribute... Just a friemdly reminder

Comment: @SamuelAialaFerreira I don't get the <a> part?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/g1Lkzhks/2/

```js
$('button').click(function() {

  if( $(this).attr('id') === 'positive'){ 
      $('button#positive').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('button#negative').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
      $('button#negative').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('button#positive').prop('disabled', false);
  }
  
   $.ajax({
    //like unlike for mysql database
    type:'POST',
    url:'ratinglike.php',
    data:'id='+id+'&type='+type,
    success:function(msg){
        if(msg == 'err'){
            alert('Some problem occured, please try again.');
        }else{
            $('#'+target).html(msg);
        }
   }
 });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<button type="submit" class="fa fa-thumbs-up" id="positive"></button>
<span class="counter" id="like_count"></span>

<button type="submit" class="fa fa-thumbs-down" id="negative"></button>
<span class="counter" id="dislike_count"></span>
```

Updated version https://jsfiddle.net/g1Lkzhks/3/

```js
$('button').click(function() {
   $(this).prop('disabled', 'disabled').siblings('button').prop('disabled', false);
 
   $.ajax({
    //like unlike for mysql database
    type:'POST',
    url:'ratinglike.php',
    data:'id=' + $(this).attr('id') + '&type=' + type,
    success:function(msg){
        if(msg == 'err'){
            alert('Some problem occured, please try again.');
        }else{
            $('#'+target).html(msg);
        }
   }
 });
  
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" class="fa fa-thumbs-up" id="positive"></button>
<span class="counter" id="like_count"></span>

<button type="submit" class="fa fa-thumbs-down" id="negative"></button>
<span class="counter" id="dislike_count"></span>
```

I have removed your php code from HTML, please add it back.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but I don't know the reason why it's not working. @Shiladitya

Comment: @janejoe ...What is not working??? What error you are getting in the browser console???

Comment: No error but I think the problem is this what I should do with this--> function like(id,type,target){ ? where should I put this one?

Comment: <button class="fa fa-thumbs-up" id = "positive" <?php if($userlike == 1){?>disabled<?php } ?>  onClick="like(<?php echo $trow['id']; ?>,1,'like_count<?php echo $trow['id']; ?>')"></button>&nbsp;   I have this html code and I think this is because of the onClick="like" What should I do with this? @Shiladitya

Comment: Rather than having all the details in onClick, I would recommend you to have it  as a data-attribute... Let me share you something....

Comment: all right. Thank you@Shiladitya. Sorry for so many questions I'm still in the process of learning.

Comment: No worries... Can you please help in understanding **like(id,type,target)** .. Please explain me each parameter and it's use/purpose..

Comment: the id = the id number  in mysql database, type = value of 1 for like and value of 0 for dislike and the target is the part of <div> item where it should be display @Shiladtiya It looks weird why its not working on me..

Comment: sorry @Shiladitya but it's still not working on me the button is still active. Thank you.